# Past or present perfect tense for event happened last night

Tags: grammaticality, tenses, past-tense, present-perfect

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do the tenses in English correspond temporally to one another?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/21846/how-do-the-tenses-in-english-correspond-temporally-to-one-another)

Since watching TV is a completed action which happened last night, which one is correct?

> - Last night I have watched TV.
> - Last night I watched TV.

Comment: A similar example related to that question would be "I watched T.V." but my question is specially about the event happened 'last night'.

Comment: Please support our proposed sister site for [English language learners](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/41665/english-language-learners?referrer=NIy3I1OlXZ2EgMrV1X1RuQ2). Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When a clause contains a specific past time reference, such as *last night*, the normal verb form is the past tense.